# How to apply query on List objects in java

Tags: java

I am doing some project in Java. I need some help regarding applying query/filter on List objects in Java. Like we can have query in C# i.e.

```
List<ReplicaManagerCustom> replicamanager;
replicamanager.where(x=>x.Id>6)
```

I want to make my searching easy in java on list objects. Kindly help me

Comment: Are you using Java 8? Here is how you can do [lambdas](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/) in 8. The example at that link is, `Stream<Person> personsOver18 = persons.stream().filter(p -> p.getAge() > 18);` where persons is a `List<Person>`.

Comment: For early versions you can use Guava: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Comment: If you want to filter directly the original list (Java 8 too), you can use `replicamanager.removeIf(x -> x.Id>6)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it yourself, manually. I.e. using if-else structures in Java prior to Java 8. In java 8 u can use Stream with lambdas to filter them. Also you can use Google Collections, it have API for managing collections in functional style